# Ajax custom search not functioning as expected

Tags: ajax

I have a custom search I have created that is handled by an ajax call. It functions correctly for the admin but not for non-admin, but logged in, users.

Admin will get the expected results returned. A logged in user that is NOT admin will get an ajax error and never even reach the memberSearchAjax function that is added with

`add_action( 'wp_ajax_memberSearchAjax', 'memberSearchAjax' );`

It's like when the ajax request attempts to hit `admin-ajax.php` it fails in some manner, but only if the logged in user is NOT admin.

**My question... why might this Ajax request only work for Admin and not for other logged in users?**

Some code...

I enqueue and localize my custom script:

```
function memberSearch_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'memberSearch', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/memberSearch.js', array( 'jquery' ) );
    wp_localize_script( 'memberSearch', 'memberSearchObject', array(
            'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) )
    );
}

//add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'memberSearch_scripts' );
add_action( 'init', 'memberSearch_scripts' );
```

Then a fairly complex function named memberSearchAjax handles the search. I use add_action on this like so:

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_memberSearchAjax', 'memberSearchAjax' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_memberSearchAjax', 'memberSearchAjax' ); <-- added this to see if it would help... doesn't
```

My javascript ajax looks like this:

```
$('#searchMembersForm').on('submit', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $('.searchMembersLetter').removeClass('active');
            var spinner = '<div class="ajax-spinner"><img src="/wp-content/themes/foobar/images/ajax-loader.gif" /></div>';
            $('#memberSearchResults').html(spinner);
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                url: memberSearchObject.ajaxurl,
                data: {
                    'action': 'memberSearchAjax',
                    'firstName': $('#firstName').val(),
                    'security': $('#security').val(),
                    'datasource': 1
                },
                error:function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                    console.log(textStatus);
                    console.log(errorThrown);
                    console.log(jqXHR);
                    $('#memberSearchResults').html('<p>There was an error with your request. It is: <br>' + errorThrown.message + '</p>');
                },
                success: process
            });
        });
```

The success function, named "process" is quite complex so I'm not including it but non-admin users never reach it anyway.

Answer (score 1):

OK... this turns out to be due to a chunk of code I thought was unrelated. In an effort to keep users out of wp-admin I had added:

```
function foobar_redirect_admin() {
    if( !current_user_can( 'edit_posts' ) ) {
        wp_redirect( site_url() );
        exit;
    }
}

add_action( 'admin_init', 'foobar_redirect_admin' );
```

And that would redirect non-admin users away from `admin-ajax.php` as well as the wp-admin backend which caused the ajax request to fail.

Comment: +1 I also made a mistake with aborting on `is_admin()` once, scratching my head for a day why this wouldn't work - turned out that AJAX always _is_ admin.